# console-setup causes apt-get update to hang

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, apt-get

I want to automatically install apache2 on my EC2 instance during first load.  I am using the base Ubuntu 16.04 LTS image:

```
ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-20180522 (ami-a4dc46db)
```

My user data script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install apache2 -y
```

Upon logging in, and waiting very patiently, I found that the apache2 was not getting installed.  Since this script runs as root, I couldn't see the output as if I ran it manually, so I redirected all output to a log file.

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y &>/var/log/erich
```

Here's the part that hangs, waiting user input:

```
Setting up console-setup (1.108ubuntu15.4) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Configuring console-setup
-------------------------


  1. ARMSCII-8         8. ISIRI-3342    15. ISO-8859-16  22. ISO-8859-8
  2. CP1251            9. ISO-8859-1    16. ISO-8859-2   23. ISO-8859-9
  3. CP1255            10. ISO-8859-10  17. ISO-8859-3   24. KOI8-R
  4. CP1256            11. ISO-8859-11  18. ISO-8859-4   25. KOI8-U
  5. GEORGIAN-ACADEMY  12. ISO-8859-13  19. ISO-8859-5   26. TIS-620
  6. GEORGIAN-PS       13. ISO-8859-14  20. ISO-8859-6   27. UTF-8
  7. IBM1133           14. ISO-8859-15  21. ISO-8859-7   28. VISCII

Encoding to use on the console:
```

I can `apt-mark hold` that package as a stop-gap measure, but that isn't a solution.  How can I set the default encoding type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling some of the debconf errors my script encounters, [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22466255/4468423) [questions](https://serverfault.com/q/327950/460947) [answered](https://askubuntu.com/q/506158/768139) all seem to have the same thing in common - remote execution via SSH.  This also seems to be Amazon's method of executing user data scripts when instances are provisioned.

These SSH connections seem to not have access to certain environment variables or default configuration data, so explicitly setting these helps reduce the errors.  Setting the `DEBCONF_FRONTEND=noninteractive` environment variable as [suggested here](https://superuser.com/a/1332550/409879) and on other questions does not do the trick in this particular case.

I was able to set the default encoding (which caused my script to hang) for the console-setup package by using `debconf-set-selections` to update the configuration database prior to the first call to `apt-get`.  It takes a file as argument, so the configuration line can be written to a temporary file and deleted afterwards:

```
echo "console-setup   console-setup/charmap47 select  UTF-8" > encoding.conf
debconf-set-selections encoding.conf
rm encoding.conf
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

Additionally, I was able to suppress many of the debconf warnings by adding `export TERM=xterm` to the top of the script.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the following environment variable at the top of your script: `export DEBCONF_FRONTEND=noninteractive`; refer to the manual for further explanation (see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man7/debconf.7.html).
Also, to be really sure, add the `-qq` switch to `apt-get`.

Pay attention that I use `export` as it will propagate the environment variable to the current environment and the child ones (contrary to the `VAR=VALUE` notation). This is necessary because `apt-get` will spawn other processes to configure the packages.

This is an excerpt from the Bash man page:

> export [-fn] [name[=word]] ... export -p The supplied names are marked
>   for automatic export to the environment of subsequently executed
>   commands. If the -f option is given, the names refer to functions...

Hope this helps!

Comment: i added that to the top of the script, but `apt-get -qq install console-setup` still seems to ignore this directive.